# Why does npm update do more, after running npm install first?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I just discovered that `npm install` is not enough to correctly get a new project into shape based on the `package.json` of an existing one.

I copied the `package.json` and did `npm install` and was suprised to find that the cloned project did not work.

I diffed the `node_modules` directory and to my suprise there were packages in the source that were not in the clone.

Then I ran `npm update` and lo and behold more packages were added and the cloned project ran.

Why is that?